# extract colname

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I need to get colnames but just want one colname in each line so could you please help how to change below command.

```
head -n 1 betas_1.csv >col.names
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one column per line you can use `awk`, it can split the column names by commas, here the command for what you want:

```
head -n 1 betas_1.csv | awk -F ',' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}' > col.names
```

Answer (score 1):

```
head -n 1 betas_1.csv | sed 's/,/\n/g'
```

Comment: you didn't provide an example .csv file so I had to guess... edited.

Answer (score 0):

Any of:

```
head -n 1 betas_1.csv | tr ',' '\n' >col.names

sed 's/,/\n/g;q' betas_1.csv >col.names

awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS="\n"} {$1=$1; print; exit}' betas_1.csv >col.names

perl -F, -ne 'print join "\n", @F; last' betas_1.csv >col.names
```

or (using the python-based `csvkit`)

```
csvstat --names betas_1.csv >col.names
```

(although this includes a column index by default).